# pytest raises, how to also check if code handles exception correctly

Tags: python, pytest

Let's say I have a code, with a function `my_operation` imported that raises an `Exception` everytime it is called:

```
from some_other_module import my_operation
import logging

class MyClass:
    def my_function(cls):
        try:
           my_operation()
        except Exception as exc:
           logging.info("something went wrong")
           raise
```

And a pytest:

```
def test_my_function():
    t_object = MyClass()
    with pytest.raises(Exception):
         t_object.my_function()
```

Now if I run my test, pytest will stop running at `my_operation()` when it raises the exception, but the handling by the code itself is not run. I actually want to also test if the logging is done. Is there a way to tell pytest to let the code handle the exception first, and then check the raising of the exception after the handling itself?

Comment: Just mock `logging.info` and check the mock using `assert_called_with` as usual after the `pytest.raises` block.

Comment: If you want to verify an error was printed you can also use the caplog or capsys fixtures and not have to do the mock by yourself. See https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/logging.html#caplog-fixture and https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/capture-stdout-stderr.html#accessing-captured-output-from-a-test-function. Had it been a different custom logic then mocking it and asserting it's called is a good solution